# заменить src в картинках на новый ,имя оставить в notepade++?

Tags: notepad++

есть несколько десятrов  разных картинок в html
тут все что перед название картинки не повторяетсz то есть в папке /r/
src="/r/07851423-BAFE-489A-9BD6-019F9505B064/izhavia.png"
в подпапках лежат картинки 
мне надо все их положить(перепрописать путь в html в новой попке они уже есть) в
 [https://l-tour.org/public_html/wp-content/uploads/Авиакомпания/название](https://l-tour.org/public_html/wp-content/uploads/%D0%90%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) картинки

```
src="/r/07851423-BAFE-489A-9BD6-019F9505B064/izhavia.png"
```

заменить на

```
src="https://l-tour.org/public_html/wp-content/uploads/Авиакомпания/$1"
```

Comment: Непонятно что на что нужно заменить и что где оставить. И в чем собственно проблема тоже непонятно. Есть функция "Заменить", чем она не устраивает?

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял то

```
Найти: src="\/r\/(.*)"
Заменить: src="https://l-tour.org/public_html/wp-content/uploads/Авиакомпания/$1"
```

Если "07851423-BAFE-489A-9BD6-019F9505B064" этот код тоже надо убрать то:

```
Найти: src="\/r\/(.*?)/(.*)"
Заменить: src="https://l-tour.org/public_html/wp-content/uploads/Авиакомпания/$2"
```